# Under what circumstances would Julia allocate memory to single digits?

Tags: memory, julia

Suppose I write this function

```
    function test_function(T)
        c = 1
        d = 31
        q = 321
        b = 32121
        a = 10
        for i in 1:T
            c = d + q + b + a
        end
    end
```

There will be no memory allocation. However, in my own code, I wrote a similar loop, but I encounter a huge amount of memory allocation. I can't share the entirety of my code, but when I used `--track-allocation=user`, I see the following results

```
    80000     q      = 3
        -     p      = 0.1
        -     p_2    = 3
        -     q_2    = .2
        -
   240000     r      =  p - p_2 + q_2 - q;
```

The code above is in a for loop. This is just strange to me - why would Julia ever allocate memory to single digits?

Comment: The key here is type stability. Your code is doing conversions between `Int` and `Float64`

Comment: @OscarSmith How can I resolve this issue? Do you happen to have an example? Thanks!

Comment: Try `q = 3.0` and `p2=2.0`

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel it helped!

Comment: This is very strange. Type promotions like this should have zero cost. And they _definitely_ should not trigger _allocations_! What's going on?

Comment: It's not a complete [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  There must be other assignments to `q` and `r` that we're not seeing here.